# How to count users' unique activity dates across many tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table A, with username,min_date and 5 more Tables B/C/D/E/F (representing products) with username,date. Each entry in the the latter tables represents that said user was active on that day.

I want to get for each user, where A.min_date >= than B/C/D/E/F.date, a count of the unique dates they were active. For instance, when a user was active in many products for a given day that should count as 1. This is for SQL Server and I'm not sure what is the best approach. Appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: A simple union will remove the duplicates: `select username, count(*) from (select username, date from B union select username, date from C union select username, date from D union ...) t group by username`

Comment: Hi, can you explain the first statement? How does union remove duplicates?

Comment: `union all` would not remove duplicates. `union` does remove repeated rows. That's how it operates. Either way you can use `count(distinct date)` to get the same result.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. Post it as an answer if you like and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Needs sample data and desired results to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.username, count(*)
from A a inner join (
    /* duplicate results will be removed by the union */
    select username, date from B union
    select username, date from C union
    select username, date from D union
    select username, date from E union
    select username, date from F
) u on u.username = a.username
where a.min_date >= u.date
group by username;
```

If the optimizer doesn't push the date filter down to the tables participating in the union then those could be moved down into the individual queries.

Comment: Also, an extra question, would it make a difference if the min_date filter is on the where or the on clause?

Comment: @henrycmcjo No, not with an inner join.